# HID halogen headlmp controler

Tags: halogen

Is there a specific name for a automotive headlamp controller that when energized, will start at , say 3volts & ramp to 12volts? This would usually be used for HID or high intensity halogen lamps to prolong lamp life.

Answer (score 2):

HID lamps are completely different from halogen lights- they use a ballast with a a state machine to control the startup current profile after discharge is achieved. They operate around 100V so your 3-12V makes no sense. Here is what start-up looks like (from this [site](http://electronicdesign.com/lighting/build-efficient-hid-lamp-driver-circuit)):

[image]

---

As to halogens- there is no evidence that ramping voltage at start-up will substantially extend the life of halogen bulbs (the fact they tend to fail at startup is not evidence), so I would say the appropriate name for such a controller would be 'scam'.